# User input value code to validate

Tags: java, validation

In my CIS 220 Java Application 2 class, we have just went over the use of objects and classes with constructors and such. The whole goal of this assignment is to utilize a class and its methods to get the user employee data. I feel I've more or less finished the whole thing, but there is one last part. The data must be validated, as explained in this screenshot link http://puu.sh/7vzeI.jpg

I would assume employee ID needs to be 9 characters long as a string. The pay rate and hours worked must be doubles. Sadly I have no idea what sort of code I need in order to validate it in the class. I figured it was a while loop but it didn't seem to work.

Here is the main java method:

```
public class Project3 {

 static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Employee worker1 = new Employee();

    worker1.getEmployeeName();

    worker1.getEmployeeNum();

    worker1.getPayRate();

    worker1.getEmployeeHours();

    System.out.println("Employee Name: " + worker1.printEmployeeName());
    System.out.println("Employee ID: " + worker1.printEmployeeNum());
    System.out.println("Pay Rate: $" + worker1.printPayRate());
    System.out.println("Hours Worked: " + worker1.printHoursWorked());
    worker1.getNetPay();
}

}
```

These are the methods in a class titled "Employee" which are used by main:

```
public String getEmployeeName()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the employee's name: ");
    employeeName = console.nextLine();
    return employeeName;      
}

// Method that prompts the user to enter their hours worked, then returns it as the reference
public double getEmployeeHours()
{

    System.out.println("Enter the number of hours worked(a numeric value between 0.0 and 100.0): ");
    hoursWorked = console.nextDouble();
    return hoursWorked;
}

// Method that prompts the user to enter their employee ID, then returns it as the reference
public String getEmployeeNum ()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the employee's ID: ");
    employeeNum = console.nextLine();
    return employeeNum;
}


// Method that prompts the user to enter their pay rate, then returns it as the reference
public double getPayRate()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the employee's pay rate (a numeric value): ");
    payRate = console.nextDouble();
    return payRate;
}
```

Please forgive me if the format of this question is hideous, as I am still quite new to stack overflow.

Comment: Separate your input/output from your data structures.

Comment: Sorry, cant say I fully understand.

Comment: Your data structure here is the class named `Employee`. Instead of having your input done in methods in the `Employee`, instead move it to a separate class. You can then use setters and getters to set/get that data. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html).

Comment: Ah I see, but sadly we are only supposed to use one class.

Comment: Then make your input/output somewhere separate than your getters/setters but still part of the class.

Comment: So in a separate method? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not be clear on the concept of return methods. There is no point in making a return method if you are not going to use the returned value at any point. For example

```
public String getEmployeeName()
{
  System.out.println("Please enter the employee's name: ");
  employeeName = console.nextLine();
  return employeeName;      
}

// in the other class 

worker1.getEmployeeName();
```

You never assign the String "worker1.getEmployeeName()" to anything so making this a return statement is useless. What I would do is that I would remove the getter methods aka "worker1.printEmployeeName()" and do this instead:

```
String name = worker1.printEmployeeName();
System.out.println("Employee Name: " + name);
```

Then in the method "printEmployeeName()" I would add my checks to see if the input was valid or not. like so:

(I don't think the name could have an invalid input except for maybe if it was null, so I will use the number instead.)

Okay so to validate the information I would do this:

```
public String getEmployeeNum ()
{
  while(true)
  {
    System.out.println("Please enter the employee's ID: ");

    try{
      employeeNum = console.nextInt(); //this should be getting an integer not the line 
    }catch(Exception e){
      employeeNum = 0;
    }

    if(String.valueOf(employeeNum).length() == 9)
      return String.valueOf(employeeNum); // this will break you out of your loop and return the value

    else{
      System.out.println("Invalid input..."); 
      continue;
    }
  } 
}
```

Now I'll try an explain the code above

Because we are using "console.nextInt();" in order to check if what the user enters is not a string, a double or anything else that is not a integer I used a try catch statement. If you are unfamiliar with how the try catch works, it basically checks if there is an error with the code in the " try{ } " part and if there is do what is in the "catch(Exception e) { } " block. I could go in to more detail on it but that explains it enough for now. So if there is a problem with the input or we find an "error" with it we set the employeeNum to "0" (You'll see why in the next part).

Then we move on to the if statement "if(String.valueOf(employeeNum).length() == 9)" basically this will turn our input into a String so we can check the length (Remember if there is an error with the input the employeeNum will be "0" with the length of "1")

If the input is valid (9 numbers long) we then return it "return employeeNum;"

If it is not valid (Not long enough or too long) we tell the user that there was an error, and we restart the process.

I hope this helps some or at least gives you an idea on what to do next!

If you want to read and learn some more:

Try Catch : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Edit: (A Hint) 
When you check if the values are doubles for the pay rate and hours use something like this:

```
try {
 hoursWorked = console.nextDouble();
}catch(Exception e){
 hoursWorked = -1.0;
}
if(hoursWorked > 0.0)
 return hoursWorked; 
// the end should be the same as the other example :)
```